# sed bash variable to delete a line in file

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to do specific operations in a file, defining the index on 1 and doing operations line-by-line, deleting the contents of line with `sed -i -e "{a}d"` file as they go
the problem is it only seems to be downloading the line 1 by one, for example, on a file with

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

the result is 2 3 5, so only downloading 1 and 4.
What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
a=0
filename="$1"
while read -r line; do
    echo $a
    name="$line"
    Operation
    sed -i -e "${a}d" $1
    let a+=1
done < "$filename"
```

From comment: What I intent to do is:

- Echo the current line it's on
- Performs an operation on the file (in this case wget)
- Delete the line it just downloaded
- Increase the current line
- Until there are no more lines

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "downloading". Note that you are _changing_ the file in each iteration. Therefore, in iteration `n`, you will not delete line that was `n` in the original data.

Comment: Please help us understand what you intend to do. Otherwise we can only guess, and not really help you.

Comment: This echoes the current line it's on, then perfoms an operation on the file (in this case wget), then deletes the line it just downloaded and then increases the current line until there are no more lines. I know I could use another wget flag, but this is for a specific need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure you selected is incorrect.

Assuming the value of `a` is started at `1`: **a=1**

When the script reads the `filename` on the `done<"$filename"` line the contents of the file (as it is at that point in time) are read in. Then, you modify the same file **in-place** by removing one line (lets assume the first), then the next read will take the second original line (now the first on the file) but will remove line index 2 (which is the third now) on the present file. So on and so forth.

To see what happens, run this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
a=1
filename=infile
seq 5 >"$filename"

while read -r line; do
    echo "Read line $line for index $a"
    echo "Will remove line $(sed "${a}!d" "$filename")"
    sed -ie "${a}d" "$filename"
    echo;echo next
    let a+=1
done < "$filename"
```

That will do this:

```
$ ./script
Read line 1 for index 1
Will remove line 1

next
Read line 2 for index 2
Will remove line 3

next
Read line 3 for index 3
Will remove line 5

next
Read line 4 for index 4
Will remove line 

next
Read line 5 for index 5
Will remove line 

next
```

As you can see, lines 1,3,5 got removed.

To do it correctly: either

- start at the end
- store an index on an additional file
- or re-start the process only for the first line of the file until the file is empty.

Implementing third option with tools you already know:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

filename=infile
seq 5 >"$filename"

while [[ -s "$filename" ]]; do
    name=$(head -n1 "$filename")
    echo wget "$name"
    sed -i '1d' "$filename"
done
```

Comment: thanks for the help, really insightful and solved my issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO editing a file that you are reading is fraught with peril. Let me suggest different solution:

- read the input list (`urls.lst`) line by line
- `wget` the URL
- if successful append the URL to a second file (`received.lst`)

If the process is interrupted and you want to restart with a list of URLs you haven't got yet, you can obtain that list with:

```
diff --new-line-format="" --unchanged-line-format=""  urls.lst received.lst
```